# How to put a string in a vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I read a file to a string. The file looks like the following:

```
   x        y          z
57.016998 6.841027 -14.977446
53.777576 5.513538 -19.883400
51.014915 3.275565 -26.822357
48.367588 4.105481 -18.890682
```

I want to put this string to a vector<3>, xyz. Is this possible? I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: 3 objects in vector? can you please write them down?

Comment: 3 floats. I want a vector of floats. vector size should be 3.

Comment: so how your vector will looks like?

Comment: vector<0> should contain the x values from the string. vector<1> y, vector<2> z.

Comment: which x value since there are many of them?

Comment: do you want to read just one line?

Comment: Can't I have a vector with multiple values

Comment: How about a struct that has 3 values (x,y,z)? Then have a vector of these structs since you have multiple rows.

Comment: can you read all strings into vector? x, y, z, x, y, z, ... , z ?

Comment: I guess I'll need three vectors, x y and z. And add to those vectors the floats in the string.

Comment: why you cannot have a single vector with all strings?

Comment: Before going further, what is the goal with these values you're reading in? If it is to process each row as one entity, the approach of having three separate vectors is not the best way to do this. WHat I suggested (which you didn't respond to) is to have a struct that has x, y, and z, and then have a single vector of that struct.

Comment: The goal of these coords is to use each row as one entity. I have to graph them on xyz plane.

Comment: @HellMan - Well, processing them as separate vectors is not the approach to take, as that will just get too messy.  See the answer below.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with structs, I think they are almost like classes but what would be the difference if you just used 3 vectors without a struct.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Go ahead and do it!

Comment: @HellMan: Structs _are_ classes.

Comment: @Hell Man - The difference is that you are treating one row as one entity, and not juggling and maintaining three separate and disjoint entities.  What if you sort on the x coordinate -- you now have to write the code to not only sort on x, but make sure that you bring y and z along for the ride if you make them 3 separate vectors.  Also, imagine if you want to have other attributes associated with the coordinates, like a string label?  Are you now going to have four vectors?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try this and I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite simple:

```
struct Vector3
{
    float x, y, z;
};

int main()
{
    std::string input = "57.016998 6.841027 -14.977446\n";
    std::stringstream ss(input);

    std::vector<Vector3> Vertices; // list of vertices
    Vector3 v;
    ss >> v.x;
    ss >> v.y;
    ss >> v.z;
    Vertices.push_back(v);

    return 0;
};
```

This should be sufficient for creating a fully working solution. A slight note however: std::stringstream is a simple, yet not the fastest solution.

As a bonus, if you are loading a huge amount of vertices, I really recommend looking into string tokenizers, though they might be a bit too much for a beginner.
Using tokenziers, your end code would look like the following:

```
TokenStr buffer("57.016998 6.841027 -14.977446\n"); // custom tokenizer class

while (buffer)
{
    Vector3 v;
    v.x = buffer.nextFloat(); // grab next float, skipping whitespace
    v.y = buffer.nextFloat();
    v.z = buffer.nextFloat();
    Vertices.push_back(v);
}
```

A few notes:

- Tokenizers don't consume any dynamic memory
- Tokenizers are extremely efficient and fast
- Tokenizers are usually custom written by the programmer
- Best tokenizers never modify source buffer
- C stdlib has strtok, which however modifies source buffer and as such is not ideal

**Edit:**
Thanks to a reminder from Ben Voigt, you can easily achieve this with just the C standard library, without using any custom tokenizer wrapper classes:

```
const char* str = "57.016998 6.841027 -14.977446\n27.016998 1.841027 -44.977446";

while (*str)
{
    Vector3 v;
    v.x = strtof(str, (char**)&str);
    v.y = strtof(str, (char**)&str);
    v.z = strtof(str, (char**)&str);
    Vertices.push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: If you do decide to make a tokenizer, the standard library function `std::strtol` is 90% of what you need.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, you are correct. :) C stdlib strtof/strtol and strpbrk are sufficient to implement such a class with trivial effort. Good point!

Comment: @Jorma: When whitespace separated, as these values are, no `strpbrk` needed.

Comment: How can i have multiple objects in the vectors? Because my file is large like I showed in the question above, I will need to make alots of objects, therefor wouldn't I be using to much memory.

Comment: @HellMan std::vector is a dynamic array that contains objects of Vector3. Each Vector3 is 12 bytes and very efficient. If your Vertices vector grows to 1000 elements, it will take 12KB of memory, but there's no way around that. Either way a large vector is a quite good solution, so I wouldn't worry. To access individual elements use the array accessor ´Vertices[i]´ or a ranged-for-loop.

Comment: My string is not one, I can'y figure out how can i iterate until end of line and get xyz and then go to next line and get the xyz?

Comment: Look at the last example in my post. It iterates through the input string by loading 3 floats at a time, constructs a Vector3 and then pushes it into the array. It skips all whitespace, so it doesn't care about spaces or newlines. All you need to do is load the file contents with fopen and fread.

Comment: I have already read the entire file to a string. Should I not added the file directly to a string.

Comment: Does the file always include "   x    y   z   \n" as the first line? You can skip it with: 
    const char* str = "  x  y  z  \n1234.0 1234.0 1234.0\n...";
    str = strchr(str, '\n'); // this skips until the first newline

Comment: Thanks for that. How can I print the Vertices to confirm that it works? Cout will not work.

Comment: for (Vector3& v : Vertices)
    printf("{ %f, %f, %f }\n", v.x, v.y, v.z);

Comment: Hey, you have been very helpful Jorma. But I have another question, How can I find the max x, max y, max z in the vector?

Comment: You would again have to iterate over the Vertices vector:
`float xMax = -FLT_MIN, yMax = -FLT_MIN, zMax = -FLT_MIN;
for (Vector3& v : Vertices)
{
    xMax = std::max(xMax, v.x);
    yMax = std::max(yMax, v.y);
    zMax = std::max(zMax, v.z);
}
`
Notice the -FLT_MIN, because you might have all negative values.

Answer (score 0):

To read all strings from file into vector:

```
fstream f;
f.open( "file.txt", std::ios::in);
if (!f) return -1;
vector<string> strings;
std::copy( istream_iterator<string > (f),                 // copy file content
        istream_iterator<string > (), std::back_inserter( strings)); // to vector
f.close();
```

To read to three vectors:

```
std::vector<string> x;
std::vector<string> y;
std::vector<string> z;

fstream f;
f.open( "file.txt", std::ios::in);
if (!f) return -1;
std::string line;

while( std::getline( f, line)) {
   std::istringstream is(line);
   x.push_back( *is++);
   y.push_back( *is++);
   z.push_back( *is);
}
f.close();
```